# How To Set PHP Authorization Header

Tags: php, header, authorization

I'm trying to set an authorization header in PHP which can be retrieved by Node.js but I'm doing something incorrectly because the header never seems to get set properly. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$username = 'user';
$password = '123';
header("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password));
```

Comment: Why would you set a basic authorization header from the server?

Comment: Did you make sure nothing else has echo'd out prior to the header function use?

Comment: @IncredibleHat yes, nothing is being echo'd.

Comment: @Devon my goal is to to set the authorization header with a jwt and retrieve that jwt in node. Users are logging in once with PHP and I'm trying to avoid them having to log in again when using the node server. I was led to believe this is the best course of action to accomplish the goal.